# Restrict access to Redshift tables, only grant access to a View

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Using Redshift on AWS. We've got a DB with a view we want to expose to customers. The view that makes our various underlying tables look like one large uber-table (a customer requirement). This is a constantly updating set of large data, so taking a snapshot and copying it somewhere isn't an option...unless there's some insanely fast way to do that every few minutes.

We don't want the customer to see our underlying tables. Not just prevent them from querying those tables, but unable to see that they even exist. Doesn't look like that's possible with GRANT.

Is there some other way to prevent seeing those underlying table names? Or maybe some clever work around to expose the view in a separate database from the underlying tables. Doesn't seem possible to have a view reference another db, but that's why I'm here asking for ideas :)

Comment: You should be able to revoke access to all the tables for that DB user, then grant access to the VIEW. For some examples, see: [PostgreSQL Privileges and Security - Locking Down the Public Schema | Severalnines](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/postgresql-privileges-and-security-locking-down-public-schema) (Redshift is based on PostgreSQL).

Comment: I believe that you are correct, you cannot stop them seeing the table names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stored procedure.

"For fine-grained access control, you can create stored procedures to perform functions without giving a user access to the underlying tables. For example, only the owner or a superuser can truncate a table, and a user needs write permission to insert data into a table. Instead of granting a user permissions on the underlying tables, you can create a stored procedure that performs the task. You then give the user permission to run the stored procedure.

A stored procedure with the DEFINER security attribute runs with the privileges of the stored procedure's owner. By default, a stored procedure has INVOKER security, which means the procedure uses the permissions of the user that calls the procedure."

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have data and tables in db1.

So, you create a schema(s1) in db1 and create all views based on tables in db1.  Then create a role like db1_s1_reader having read access of schema s1 and assign this role to all the users whoever wants to read data. Post this revoke access to users from db1 if they already have data access.